# Angular loading template inline

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In an angular js 1.2.22 version code, I saw this in the HTML

```
<div class="mainContent" ng-include="content"> </div>
```

and in its corresponding controller, I see this.

```
$scope.content = 'templates/contents/home.html';
```

I see its making an Ajax call to load the template.

I am working on improving the speed of the content display and I did some optimizations like minifying the javascript code and minifying css

My doubt is how to make this inline - without making the Ajax call. So, that I could check if there is visible difference in speed of the content showing up for this template?

I tried the gulp-angular-templatecache to cache templates but, it did not work. 
Is there any workaround for this so that I can make this template inline ?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is Angular's [`$templateCache`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache).

Depending on your task runner, you might want to give [`gulp-angular-templatecache`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache) or [`grunt-angular-templatecache`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templatecache) a try.

Comment: I used the template cache, but, its still loading the template from Ajax response. 
I see that, it uses this <div class="mainContent" ng-include="content"> </div> and in its corresponding controller code, its written like this $scope.content = 'templates/contents/home.html';
Is there any way I can make this template inline ?

Comment: Check your dist js file, if the templates are put in the $templateCache using the correct path. If not, they may not be included in your build process or use the wrong path.

Comment: I can see the new template.js file was generated and it was placed in the js folder - as I given in the gulp configuration. And I concatenated this template.js file to create the app.min.js file to create the single js file using gulp. Still its making Ajax call to load template. 

I tested this on a normal simple Angular js app, and it worked. In this case, I wonder, if using ng-include="content" is the problem.

Comment: `ngInclude` is not the problem. This should work fine. Check **the content** of your `template.js` file and see, if the paths in `$tempalteCache.put()` (e.g. `templates/contents/home.html`) are correct. If that's the case, make sure the options `standalone` and `module` for `angular-templatecache` task are correct.